# Form the differential equation satisfying the relation $\sqrt{1+x^2}+\sqrt{1+y^2}=\lambda(x\sqrt{1+y^2}-y\sqrt{1+x^2})$.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, contest-math

> Form the differential equation satisfying the relation $\sqrt{1+x^2}+\sqrt{1+y^2}=\lambda(x\sqrt{1+y^2}-y\sqrt{1+x^2})$, where $\lambda$ is an arbitrary constant.

**My Attempt:**

I wrote $\frac ND=\lambda$

then I differentiated making RHS zero. But LHS became unwieldy.

I tried substituting $x=\tan\theta, y=\tan\phi$ but still couldn't conclude.

The given answer is $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1+y^2}{1+x^2}$

Comment: $d(\frac{N}{D})=0$ is a perfectly good differential equation.  Nowhere in the question did it ask you to simplify it.

Comment: @user10354138 valid point but I was wondering if we could reach to the given answer with some clever manipulations.

Comment: Well, start with $DN'=D'N$ and so $\sqrt{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}(x\sqrt{1+y^2}-y\sqrt{1+x^2})(\sqrt{1+x^2}+\sqrt{1+y^2})'$ equals $\sqrt{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}(x\sqrt{1+y^2}-y\sqrt{1+x^2})'(\sqrt{1+x^2}+\sqrt{1+y^2})$ which simplifies down to $(\sqrt{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}-xy+1)((1+x^2)y'-(1+y^2))=0$.